# Can I use Google Chart Gallery in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-charts, google-chart-api

Google Spreadsheets has column charts but I want to use "draw Annotations" like [this](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) (Annotations). Column chart doesn't show bar value as "draw Annotations" on top.

My chart included these:

First Column: Sales Group,
Second Column:Number of product sold,
Third Column: Turnover

I [found the code below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21877678/google-chart-labelling-stacked-column-charts) but it doesn't work on my sheet.

```
 function getValueAt(column, dataTable, row) {
       return dataTable.getFormattedValue(row, column);} 
 function setLabelTotal(dataTable) {//dataTable must have role: annotation
 var SumOfRows = 0;   

 for (var row = 0; row < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); row++) {
     SumOfRows = 0;
     for (var col = 0; col < dataTable.getNumberOfColumns(); col++) {

         if (dataTable.getColumnType(col) == 'number') {
             SumOfRows += dataTable.getValue(row, col);
         }
         if(dataTable.getColumnRole(col) == 'annotation')
         {dataTable.setValue(row, col, SumOfRows.toString());}
     }
 } }
```

Comment: There is a "problem" with the page linked in the first line of the question 
[Google Charts - Chart Gallery - Visualization: Column Chart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart) : 
It include a carousel of demos that is time controlled and can't be stopped from the page itself. By the other hand, the code is not in the page itself, it could be found by clicking the "Code it your self in JSFiddle".

Answer (score 2):

The Chart Gallery in [Google Developers - Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/) is a collection of demos about using code to create charts. This charts can't be inserted in a Google Sheets but they could a Google spreadsheet as data source.

It's worth to say that the Column Chart that can be inserted in a Google spreadsheet, but could be a bit tricky to add the annotations.

For each series, use two columns, one for bar values, the other one for annotations. [Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CO6U4C19j_AiEDfImq0wBasSCkxulORaLWUvpihvE6w/edit?usp=sharing)
[image: Bar Chart with annotations]

## Notes:

From [Google Charts - Overview - Using Charts and Spreadsheets - Google Spreadsheets](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets)

> ### Introduction
>
> Google Charts and Google Spreadsheets are tightly integrated. You can place a Google Chart inside a Google Spreadsheet, and Google
>   Charts can extract data out of Google Spreadsheets. This documentation
>   shows you how to do both.

Comment: Actually i am not good at writing code so This is  [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r7GU31LtjcXXACc0-tss6Eq0J8XT11l2sUfYpKPNFRk/pubhtml). How can i use [Annotations](https://jsfiddle.net/7ey02eaL/) in this sheet?

Comment: If you don't want to learn to write code, then instead of looking at [Annotations](https://jsfiddle.net/7ey02eaL/) look at [Adding annotations to a chart - Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2382813?hl=en), [Annotated Timeline - Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1047432?hl=en). Then consider to edit your question to make clearly the kind of answer that you are looking for, i.e. How to add annotations to built-in charts in Google Sheets?

Comment: Added a chart based in ["my sheet"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r7GU31LtjcXXACc0-tss6Eq0J8XT11l2sUfYpKPNFRk/pubhtml) (the link provide in the previous comment).